# Same base for category and post

Tags: categories, permalinks, 404-error

I'd like to have the following:

Single Post `test.com/blog/new-category/post-name/`

Category `test.com/blog/new-category/`

So I changed the Permalink structure to: `/blog/%category%/%postname%/`  and the category base to `blog`. But this gives me a 404 on the post.

So I tried `blog/.` for the category base, which works. But only for the first page. On the second page it gives me a 404 for `test.com/blog/new-category/page/2/`.

I guess WP is looking for a post with the slug `page/2/`.

Does anybody had a similar problem and may know a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you implement the pagination?

Comment: `<p id="pagination"><?php echo paginate_links(); ?></p>`
Isn't that the right way?

Comment: I changed the `'format' => '?paged=%#%'` but this only gives a redirect to `/page/2/`

Answer (score 0):

- Change *Category base* to `.` (dot). Nobody knows this trick will work in the future, but there is no easy way to remove `/category/` from the URL. So, it's better to google for a plugin ([here is](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-category-url/) one of them). Yoast's SEO plugin also is able do the same.
- Set *Permalink structure* to `/blog/%category%/%postname%/`.

Then:

```
the_posts_pagination();
```

This function does not require any arguments in your case.

If you really want to use `paginate_links()`, use the right `format` argument value because pretty permalinks were already set: `page/%#%/` rather than `?paged=%#%`:

```
echo paginate_links( array('format' => 'page/%#%/') );
```

See [Pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Function_Reference) functions for more.

Comment: When I remove the Category base I have a Category Permalink linke thant: `blog/category/neue-kategorie/` - `blog/category/neue-kategorie/page/2/` which does not make sence since `blog/category/` gives me a 404 (no logical structure).
And whats the advantage of `the_posts_pagination();`?

Comment: I see. I've updated the answer.